# Is it possible to show that a method/operation returns and array of objects (rather than just a single object) in Visio 2007?

Tags: class, collections, methods, diagram, visio

I am making particular reference to producing a Static Structure (class diagram). I notice that you can set the return type to a particular object, but there appears to be no way to select that collection of objects be returned instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Select the class, go to Properties, find the Operation, click on Properties and you'll see Prefix and Suffix fields in the dialog box. You can use these fields to modify the return expression, for example:

- You can type "col " as Prefix to express a collection of objects.
- You can type "[]" as Suffix to express an array of objects.

Or anything else.